# How do I get iPhoto to recognize an older Canon PowerShot A40?

Tags: photos.app, camera, canon

I have iPhoto 9.4.2 set to open automatically when a camera is connected to my iMac. When I connect the PowerShot A40 to my iMac via USB, iPhoto does open. But there's no sign of the camera in the left side bar and no way to import any of the photos off the CompactFlash card in the camera shown in iPhoto.

How can I get this old camera to show up as Device in iPhoto so I can import the photos off of it?

Edit: it works fine on a 10.7.5-equipped MacBook Pro. Shows up in the Devices list, lets me import the photos.

Comment: Can you access the card from Image Capture (in your Applications Folder) ? Or can you via a USB Card Reader?

Comment: @terrydev No. It does not show up as a device in Image Capture. And I don't have a USB card reader on hand (hence trying to get iPhoto to recognize the camera when it's attached via USB).

Comment: Well you're in Catch 22 land I'm afriad. Canon's won't mount on the desktop so you can't access them via the Finder. Putting the Card in a USB Reader would get around that, but you don't have one of those. And neither Image Capture nor iPhoto can see the card. Usual cause: minor directory damage on the card and reformatting the card with the camera will sort that out - but it will also erase the card. So you need to get the shots off the card and then reformat. A Card Reader is inexpensive... or try bring the camera to another computer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the communication setting on your camera. I had this problem after updating and changed the general>communication>PTP. Mine was set to PC connection previously - worked!